# Unique validation by ignoring softdelete items in laravel form input validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, formvalidation.io

How can I do unique validation of a given input with database record by ignoring soft delete items in Laravel? Can anyone please answer me?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a condition to the exists rule, basically filtering the results with `deleted_at == NULL` like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'foo' => 'exists:table,column,deleted_at,NULL',
]);
```

Taylor himself answered this question on a [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1820#issuecomment-20649828).

You could also create a custom validation rule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class UniqueWithoutSoftDelete implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Your logic goes here
        // Return true to pass the validation
        // ie: return Model::where($attribute, $value)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be unique.';
    }
}
```

To implement it in your controller add:

```
use App\Rules\UniqueWithoutSoftDelete;
```

And in your controller method:

```
$request->validate([
    'foo' => ['required', new UniqueWithoutSoftDelete],
]);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it in another way...
Inside request class, write following code: `public function rules()
    {
        switch ( $this->method() ){
            case 'POST':
                return [
                    'currency_id' => ['required', Rule::unique('company_currencies')->where(function ($query) {
                            $query->where('deleted_at', Null);
                        })
                    ],
                ];
                break;
    }`

and on top of the class file place `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

Comment: Your shouldn't modify vendor code, it can create issues down the road, try extending the request class instead, but I would recommend you to use the first solution I posted, is the cleanest and it's even suggested by the creator of the framework.